# MYSQL does not start in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, xampp

I installed Xampp on Windows 7. When I try to start XAMPP, I get the following message and MySql does not start.

```
7:12:54 AM  [mysql]     Problem detected!
7:12:54 AM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"!
7:12:54 AM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
7:12:54 AM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
7:12:54 AM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

How can fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: One of your plugins in Google Chrome is hosting MySQL server / using port 3306 .

Comment: Close Chrome and try again.

Answer (score -1):

It says in the error message that Chrome is using the port that MySQL wants to use. You should be able to start MySQL after you close Chrome. I don't know why Chrome would be using that port.